# Spring 3.2 web application and android client

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have a Web application with a db and it uses spring framework, hibernate etc. I need to send data from a mobile client (iphone,android) to web application like login, insert, update  db etc. There are many ways to do that I think, however I am looking for a good solution. What would you prefer? Spring Security? REST?

Comment: You are comparing apples with oranges. REST has absolutely nothing to do with Spring Security. What do you actually want? A fat client communicating with a backend server?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes i need to login from android client and send data to db

Answer (score 0):

Yes, spring-security to secure your service, and spring-web && spring-mvc with jackson dependencies to create an annotated rest service that you can host in something like tomcat.

Comment: Thank you dollery, you mean spring security for login and REST for requests, right? thank you.

Comment: @user2489341, yes that would be the conclusion.